# How do I correctly include a json file into custom WP theme?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, lottie

I am trying to include a lottie animation into my custom wp theme.  The problem I am running into is that my path is not finding the json file for some reason. Here is some code:

```
 <div class="container container__grid container__grid--justify-center">
     <div class="plant" data-file='plant'></div>
 </div>
```

and the js

```
let plant = document.getElementsByClassName("plant");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(plant, (icon) => {
  console.log(icon.dataset.file);

  var anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: icon,
    path: `lottie/${icon.dataset.file}.json`,
    renderer: "svg",
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
  });
  console.log(anim.path);

  icon.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    anim.setDirection(1);
    anim.play();
  });
  icon.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    anim.setDirection(-1);
    anim.play();
  });
});
```

I put my lottie file right in the root directory to make the path as straight forward as possible, but it's still not being found.  I've included a screenshot of the console error as well.

[image]

How do properly include a lottie animation into my custom wp theme?

Comment: You need to go to the folder and check if it is really there and also check if you can access it through the browser. In my view the json file is not there on that folder.

Comment: Yes, the file is there and it does open in the browser. I created a simple html project to test it out and it works there.  This is likely a Wordpress/php issue I can't figure out.